# How to delete a group in Fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm working on a fabric application which features grouping and ungrouping. I've pretty much handled that logic, however when I ungroup (which consists of duplicating all the grouped elements, and removing the group) the "group" object persists. It's simply not removed although I am calling the remove method on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright so I figured it out. I was calling remove on the group itself, which wasn't actually doing anything. Instead I had to call remove on the canvas and pass it said group.

Comment: You could also loop through the objects of the group and remove them one by one.

Comment: Would appreciate seeing the code for this answer.